# Using the function strcmp to compare a pointer and a string

Tags: c, strcmp

Here is my code:

```
  printf("Please input a command\n");

  char *input;
  input = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);

  if(fgets(input, 50, stdin) != NULL) {
    if(strcmp(input, "end\0") == 0) {
      printf("END");
    }
  }
```

For some reason when I input 'end', it doesn't print "END". What is the problem here that is causing the loop condition to fail? `strcmp(input, "end\0") == 0` Should return 0 when the input pointer is equal to `"end\0"`? I've also tried `strcmp(input, "end") == 0` and this doesn't work either. How can I fix this?

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much for the quick reply

Comment: BTW: In `"end\0"`, `\0`has no meaning in your program.

Comment: Umpteenth duplicate. Please next time try searching with Google first.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` includes the newline. Use `strcmp(input, "end\n")`

From the documentation:

> Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first.
>
> A newline character makes fgets stop reading, **but it is considered a valid character by the function and included in the string copied to str.**

And as mentioned in comments, you do not need to include `\0` when using string literals. The nulltermination will be added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could strip newline characters \r and \n before comparing the string:

```
int length = strlen(input);

if(length>0 && input[length-1]=='\n') {
    input[length-1]='\0';
    length--;
}
if(length>0 && input[length-1]=='\r') {
    input[length-1]='\0';
    length--;
}
```

This code should be universal for windows linux and mac. Next, I've used unsafe functions like *strlen* and *strcmp* in my example, there's also strncmp that compares only specified number of bytes.

Comment: The idea is good, but you can do the same with `size_t length = strcspn(input, "\r\n"); input[length] = '\0';`.